# Gradle JettyRun can not find MyBatis mapper xml files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gradle, mybatis

I am using jettyRun task to run my application(spring mvc+ibatis+extjs) during development, but gradle can not find my Mapper.xml in the classpath.

Configuration of sqlSessionFactory in my applicationContext.xml as following:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="cn.xxxx.entity" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:/*Mapper.xml" />
</bean>
```

and get the following exception

[image]

when I change the configuration with explicit mapper.xml file name as following it works, but it's obviously not a good solution that replace the asterisk with the explicit mapper.xml name:

```
<property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:/UserMapper.xml" />
```

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Ps. I use JettyRun because I want jetty to support hot deploy during development.

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution, jst add * after classpath as following:

```
`<property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:/UserMapper.xml" />`
```